# Python: Combine AND and NOT operators?

Tags: python

`if (cond1 and cond2) or (not cond1 and not cond2):`

Is there a simpler way to write this in Python?

Comment: You mean `if (cond1 = cond2)`?

Comment: @KenWhite: that'd by a syntax error. ;-)

Comment: You want the inverse of `xor`, (so `xand`?), which is `bool(cond1) == bool(cond2)`. See the duplicate (with `!=` inverted to `==`). You can drop the `bool()` calls if both `cond1` and `cond2` are themselves boolean results.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: OK. The logic is correct; the question still asks about equality of both variables (both true or both false). Fill in the correct syntax for the language, whether that's `=`, `==`, `equals`, or something else. :-)

Comment: @SamuelLiew: yes, which is nothing more than the inversion of XOR. So `bool(a) != bool(b)` (XOR) becomes `bool(a) == bool(b)`. I do cover that in my comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If cond1 and cond2 are booleans, there certainly is:

```
cond1 == cond2
```

Comment: Completely forgot about that. Thanks!